# Delphi MapiSendMail Crashes on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: delphi, mapi, windows-7-x64, mapisendmail

I have windows 7 64-bit and my delphi sendmail crashes when trying to send an email for the second time or sometimes even just waiting for the first send mail to complete.  Same application works with windows vista.

Below is my test procedure in sending the mail:

```
procedure TForm1.SendMail(const Subject, FileName: String);
var tmpName2, PFullFilePath, PSubject : Array[0..MAX_PATH] of AnsiChar;
    MapiMessage  : TMapiMessage;
    MapiFileDesc : TMapiFileDesc;
    MError       : Cardinal;
begin
  with MapiFileDesc do
  begin
     ulReserved:=0;
     flFlags:=0;
     nPosition:=Cardinal(-1);
     StrPCopy(PFullFilePath, FileName);
     lpszPathName:=PFullFilePath;
     StrPCopy(tmpName2,ExtractFileName(FileName));
     lpszFileName:=tmpName2;
     lpFileType:=nil;
   end;

   with MapiMessage do
   begin
      ulReserved := 0;
      StrPCopy(PSubject, Subject);
      lpszSubject := PSubject;
      lpszNoteText := nil;
      lpszMessageType := nil;
      lpszDateReceived := nil;
      lpszConversationID := nil;
      flFlags := 0;
      lpOriginator := nil;
      nRecipCount := 0;
      lpRecips := nil;
      nFileCount := 1;
      lpFiles := @MapiFileDesc;
   end;

   MError:=MapiSendMail(0,Application.Handle, MapiMessage, MAPI_DIALOG or MAPI_LOGON_UI or MAPI_NEW_SESSION, 0);

   if MError<>0 then
      Raise Exception.CreateFmt(IntToStr(MError), [MError]);
end;
```

Error/Crash Message that I get:

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
>     Application Name: mapitestp.exe
>     Application Version:  0.0.0.0
>     Application Timestamp:    4d82c905
>     Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll
>     Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16559
>     Fault Module Timestamp:   4ba9b29c
>     Exception Code:   4000001f
>     Exception Offset: 000a1dcf
>     OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
>     Locale ID:    1033
>     Additional Information 1: d1ab
>     Additional Information 2: d1ab624ec7d094c26a73530c245a3468
>     Additional Information 3: d1ab
>     Additional Information 4: d1ab624ec7d094c26a73530c245a3468

Any help or idea would be very much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Is the 64 Bit MAPI version installed?

Comment: @mjn: a 32 bit app will use 32 bit mapi.

Comment: @Remko: a 32 bit app can use the 64 bit MAPI for the MapiSendMail function over a OS-provided bridge - this is documented in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941355.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Link](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=49096) at Embarcadero, it may be some Unicode issue.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the link; however, StrPCopy already converts the string to PAnsiString which is what is required by lpszPathName or lpszFileName.